# Different ways one can understand / realise the Dhamma?

Tags: vipassana, pali-canon, reference-request, meditation-recommendation

I have heard in a Dhamma talk in which different ways of understanding / realising the Dhamma was discussed. One way that was mentioned was meditation. I am wondering which Suttas this has been referenced from. Up to then my understanding was Vippasana / meditation was the one and only way.

With regard to the other ways, how does the understanding / realisation happen?

This was sometime back so I cannot remember the exact content.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an09/an09.036.than.html

"I tell you, the ending of the mental fermentations depends on the first jhana... the second jhana... the third... the fourth... the dimension of the infinitude of space... the dimension of the infinitude of consciousness... the dimension of nothingness. I tell you, the ending of the mental fermentations depends on the dimension of neither perception nor non-perception."